# How can I make my my AJAX work with my php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first foray into Javascript and AJAX (I'm reading JavaScript and JQuery, The Missing Manual). I've written this code to try to send data from a form using AJAX, to a php file which queries a database (queries work fine phpMyAdmin), return the data and display on screen using Javascript to append a div.

My sticking point is making the AJAX work with the server php page. I'm also wondering if there are steps along the way I can take to check to see if my code is working properly.

Here is what I've written so far, thanks for any help and insight:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sidework Review Screen</title>
<link href="./_resources/_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="./_resources/_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){

//var sw = "testing";
var sw = $("#switcher").val();
var tech = $("#id_techs option:selected").val();

// alert(tech);

    $.post('side_work_controller.php',
        {
        switcher: sw,
        id_techs: tech
        },  
        function(data, status){
        alert("Date: " + data + "\nStatue: " + status);
    }); // end post 
}); //end click 

}); // end ready
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
try {
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=10.5.44.12;dbname=SideProjects', $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT tech_fname, tech_lname, extension
                  FROM `techs` ORDER BY tech_lname
                  ");
$sth->execute();
$sql = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="dropshadow"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <!--<form action="side_work_controller.php" name="switcher" method="post">';-->
        <h1>Sidework Review</h1><p>
        <label for="tech_ids"><h2>Choose a Technician</h2></label><p>

            <select name="id_techs" id="id_techs"> //Builds drop down menu-->
                <?php foreach ($sql as $row){
                    echo '<option value = "' . $row['extension'] . '">' . $row["tech_fname"] . ' ' . $row["tech_lname"] . ' - ' . $row['extension'] . '</option>';
                } ?>
            </select><p>
        <input type="hidden" name="switcher" id="switcher" value="search">  

        <div id="button"><button>Review</button></div>          
    </div>  
 </div>
 <div id="bottom"></div>
</body>
</html>

EDIT:
I've discovered that part of the problem is with my button, it needs to be
<button>Review</button> not 
echo '<input type="submit" id="button" onclick="click()" value="Review">'; 
for this to work.

EDIT:
Also just worked out that the <select> and <input> tags needed id="[id name]" in order to work with the .val() function.

EDIT:
I've written a bit of the AJAX and is does send to the php file and gets some data. 

I am reposting my changes for the benefit of newbie like me. The AJAX doesn't work correctly yet.
```

Comment: to whomever downclicked me saying this questions shows no effort at research, I've spent the entire weekend and last 2 days at work reading and learning as much as I can about the 4 topics. I've done a heck of a lot of research. This is my first attempt from scratch.

Comment: Things like `echo '<div id="top"></div>';` are bad : unreadable, hard to maintain. Your IDE (if you use one) can't detect HTML errors. Have a look at [this very interesting post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/95027/2806497), or templates engines like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

Comment: @ScottMorrison I'm sure you have. but, you need to show that in your question. we aren't sitting next to you looking at your monitor. You have to tell us what is wrong with your code. As it stands now, your code should be throwing at least one syntax error (unless that's a typo in your question), and you haven't even given us that syntax error.

Comment: Actually there are two syntax errors I've found, there's also a : instead of at ;. I've fixed that and still when I hit the "Review" button nothing happens. I fixed the quote issue around the selector and I've commented out everything in the function and put in an alert box to see if I could get that up and nothing happens. I've done this since the first responses.

Comment: I've doicovered that part of the problem is with my button, it needs to be <button>Review</button> not echo '<input type="submit" id="button" onclick="click()" value="Review">'; for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you forgot to put some quotes around a selector.

There's many other mistakes:

- you forgot a ; after data array variable initialization
- this code has a problem : where is the `$('#container').html(newHTML);` when requests finish ? He does not exist.

  ```
  $.post('side_work_controller.php',data,function(data, status){
          var newHTML = data + '.</P>';
          //$('#container') does not exist at this moment 
          $('#container').html(newHTML);
      }); // end post
  ```

  You could append to document instead :

  ```
  $(newHTML).appendTo(document);
  ```
- As I said in a comment on your question, things like `echo '<div id="top"></div>';` are bad : unreadable, hard to maintain. Your IDE (if you use one) can't detect HTML errors. Have a look at [this very interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/95027/2806497), or templates engines like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)
- What are those `</body>` and `</html>` at the end of the php file ? If you choose to 'echo' your HTML (bad choice I repeat), do it until the end.

Correct this code and try to debug things by yourself. By this way I mean you should use a javascript debugger : integrated browsers consoles are pretty good nowadays. You can access it with F12 shortcut. Read documentations about it, [here for chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've found a lot of errors on my part having to do with the type of button tags I was using and also not having "id" in the element I was trying to select. I've put my updated code up. It works as far as the .val() functions being able to pull in the data from the input tags. I'm starting to read up more on AJAX now and hope to start writing that this after noon.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around your selector when you define the click action.

```
$(#button).click(function(){
```

Becomes:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
```